# Как увеличить таймаут соединения postgresql 8.4 под debian 6?

Tags: postgresql, debian, linux

При перегоне данных с ms sql express 2008 обрывает коннект. Перегоняю ручными запросами.Делаю запрос select top 40 000, проходит нормально, если более, то не перегоняет.

Comment: У вас репликация, или вы просто базу сливаете?

Answer (score 1):

```
set statement_timeout to 0;
```

- отключит таймаут